# Заполнить пустые строки значениями из последней непустой строки

Tags: sql, sql-server

В MS SQL имеется таблица, в одном из столбцов которой встречаются пустые значения. Необходимо подставить вместо них значения из ближайшей строки, идущей ранее, для которой этот столбец не пустой.

К примеру, для таблицы вида

```
Столбец1 Стобец2
1        2
6        NULL
6        7
3        9
5        NULL
9        NULL
7        5
```

Нужно получить результат вида

```
Столбец1 Стобец2
1        2
6        2
6        7
3        9
5        9
9        9
7        5
```

Столбец, для которого это нужно выполнить, только один, и он заранее известен. Максимальное число пустых строк подряд в общем случае не определено. Подскажите, пожалуйста, под запроса, которым возможно это организовать. Чувствую, что нужен какой-то цикл, но мне не хватает знаний.

Comment: В этой таблице есть какой-то уникальный ключ?

Comment: Цикл делается при помощи курсора - сам никогда не пользовался, так что навскидку не скажу точнее. Все приходящие в голову варианты с select'ом (недодуманные) неэффективные из-за повторной выборки для каждой строки.

Comment: @Qwertiy Уникального ключа нет. Есть дата, но она может повторяться. Собственно, для некоторых дат значения другого столбца не определены, и их нужно взять из даты ранее.

Comment: Без ключа апдейты не будут работать. С ключом можно сделать.

Comment: На примере 2-ой и 3-ей строк в исходной таблице. Значение столбца1 равно 6, но при этом значения столбца2 равен NULL и 7, соответственно. То есть не за что "зацепиться" чтобы обновить записи. Можно, конечно, написать курсор с проверками предыдущей и последующей записей, но это будет нетривиально.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown Как реализовать ключ для данной таблицы я представляю. Давайте считать, что Столбец1 содержит даты, и каждая дата встречается только 1 раз. Можно ли в этом случае как-то выполнить задуманное?

Comment: "Можно ли в этом случае как-то выполнить задуманное?" - да. Есть идея с вложенным select'ом, но он будет выполняться для каждой строки, что неэффективно. Подумаю, может можно как-то join присобачить, хотя не ясно, как. И предлагаю даты упростить до чисел - логика запроса от этого не должна пострадать.

Comment: @Qwertiy Заменить даты на числа тоже, думаю, возможно. Если под эффективностью понимается время на выполнение запроса, это не критично: объем данных не очень велик.

Comment: @volly проблема в том, что в SQL Server нет какого-то определенного порядка строк. т.е. нельзя сказать что вторая строка в вашей таблице - действительно вторая. порядок строк в результате любого SELECT вообще не гарантирован. так что ваша задача в терминах SQL не имеет смысла - т.к. не определено понятие "идущей ранее" строки. Ее можно решить только если есть столбец с возрастающими (или убывающими) данными. Например, даты - но не просто даты, а такие, порядок которых совпадет с "порядком" строк у вас в вопросе

Comment: Если есть дата, то нет проблем.
Достаточно взять не null значение с максимальной датой, меньшей, чем дата со значением null. Т.е. просто подзапрос в Update.

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос в такой формулировке не имеет смысла.

В SQL Server, и вообще в SQL нет понятия "строк, идущих подряд" или "предыдущей строки". Порядок строк в результате запроса не определен. Т.е. если в запросе нет ключевого слова `ORDER BY` - то никаких конкретных предположений о порядке строк в результате делать нельзя (да, есть слухи что сортировка совпадет с primary key, но [они ложны](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx)).

Это легко проверить - например, создать индекс по Column2, и сделать выборку

```sql
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Column2 IS NOT NULL
```

Результат будет отсортирован по ... column2! Причем даже если в таблице есть PK.

Соответственно, никак нельзя заполнить NULL-ы в приведенной таблице, т.к. нельзя определить строку, из которой нужно брать значение. Потому что SQL Server предпочтет практически любой поставленный на эту таблицу индекс тупому Table Spool.

Вопрос будет иметь смысл, если в таблице будет какое-то поле, значения которого идут в строго восходящем или строго нисходящем порядке. Тогда можно сказать "взять Column2 из предыдущей по значению Id (или Date, или еще что-то) строки в которой Column2 заполнено". Примерно так:

```sql
;WITH NotNulls AS (SELECT Id, Column2 FROM SomeTable WHERE Column2 IS NOT NULL),
Nulls AS (SELECT Id, Column2 FROM SomeTable WHERE Column2 IS NULL),
FilledValues AS (SELECT Nulls.Id, NotNulls.Column2, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Nulls.ID ORDER BY NotNulls.Id DESC) as RN
    FROM Nulls inner join NotNulls ON Nulls.id > NotNulls.id),
FilledWithClosest AS (SELECT * FROM FilledValues WHERE RN = 1)
SELECT * FROM FilledWithClosest
```

Впрочем, SQL Server все равно сделает в этом запросе Nested Loops, так что проще и читабельней сделать обычным подзапросом.

Или использовать объекты SQL Server, представляющие собой "слепки" таблиц, записи в которых можно перебирать в определенном порядке - курсоры.

Answer (score 0):

Как следует из условия задачи, ключи в таблицах не определены, поэтому вариант реализации средствами одной лишь базы будет нетривиальным. У меня есть рациональное предложение. Оно несколько уводит в сторону от оригинальных условий, но на мой взгляд оно правильное.

Перегружать базу черезмерной логикой не очень хорошо. Поэтому я предложил бы взять любой высокоуровневый ЯП (которым автор более-менее владеет) и реализовать логику на этом ЯП.

Этапы реализации:

1. Загоняем изначальные данные в массив (значение `NULL` можно заменить нулём или какой-нибудь другой, не встречающейся цифрой).
2. Проходимся по массиву с целью определения `NULL`'ов в столбце2.
3. Когда находим `NULL`, определяем индексы массива. То есть берем значение предыдущего элемента массива, которым будем заполнять пустоту до определенного индекса.
4. Заполняем пустоту до тех пор, пока не находим *непустоту*.
5. Продолжаем проход массива с повторением действий 1-4.

Потом получившийся массив можно будет в цикле загнать в базу. Для этого можно будет использовать то самое поле `datetime` с уникальным датами/временем.

*Если таблица очень большая, что можно загонять а базу одиночными чанками через XML merge. Но это уже техника, не имеющая отношения к вопросу.*

Мой поинт в том, что такая техника позволит существенно сэкономить время и усилия. Не нужно будет писать громоздкий курсор и отлаживать его. А вместо этого использовать высокоуровневый ЯП по его прямому назначению.

P.S. Даже если и были бы ключи, то лично я не стал бы писать курсор. Для каждой цели есть свое средство, имхо.

Answer (score 0):

На уровне идеи: COALESCE значения второго столбца с top 1 второго столбца из той же таблицы с обратной сортировкой и условием, что во втором столбце не null, а первый строго меньше.

Скорее всего, оптимизатор не сможет улучшить этот запрос и будет вызывать подзапрос для каждого null'а в лучшем случае.

В коде мне это представляется примерно так (`smth` - имя таблицы, `a`, `b` - её столбцы):

```
select
  t.a,
  coalesce(
    t.b,
    select top 1 t1.b from smth t1 where t1.a < t.a and t.b is not null order by t1.a desc
  )
order by t1.a asc
```

Написал приблизительно, вполне возможно, где-то наврал, даже в синтаксисе.

PS: Думаю, можно как-то присобачить join, но не пойму, как.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#t1', 'U') IS NOT NULL drop table #t1, #t2, #t3   --drop temp table
        --создаём 2 таблицы, одну с полем идентификатором, вторую с такой же структурой
        create table #t1
        ( I int identity
        , A int not null
        , B int null
        )

        create table #t2
        ( I int not null
        , A int not null
        , B int null
        )

        --Вставляем данные из примера
        insert into #t1
        select 1,2      union all
        select 6,NULL   union all
        select 6,7      union all
        select 3,9      union all
        select 5,NULL   union all
        select 9,NULL   union all
        select 7,5

        --вставляем с 1й во 2ю таблицу только не null записи
        insert into #t2
        select *
          from #t1
         where B is not null

        --проставляем порядковый номер записи из 1й таблицы где B только null
        select *
             , row_number() over(order by B) as "I2"
          into #t3
          from #t1
         where B is null
        /*-------------------------------1 метод--------------------------------*/
--апдейт всех строк c NULL сразу несколько раз
        --подсчитывем количество сколько раз нужно отработать циклу по методу:
        --джоинем к таблице #t3 саму себя по новому полю "I2" минус 1
        --что бы узнать какое максимально количество записей NULL где разница по столбцу I будет = 1
        --вконце добавляем +1 т.к. при джоине 1 запись с предыдущим номер не попадает
        declare @c int 
        select @c = count(
                            case when t1.I - t2.I = 1
                                 then t1.I - t2.I
                             end
                         ) + 1
          from #t3 as t1
          join #t3 as t2 on t2.I2 = t1.I2 - 1

        --по циклу апдейтим таблицу #t1 и добавляем новые записи с не NULL значением в таблицу #t2
        while (@c > 0)
        begin
            update #t1
               set B = t2.B
              from #t1 as t1
              join #t2 as t2 on t2.I = t1.I - 1
             where t1.B is null

            --добавление новых записей не NULL
            insert into #t2
            select *
              from #t1
             where B is not null
               and I not in (select I from #t2)

               set @c = @c - 1
        end
        --вывод итогового результата
        select *
          from #t1 as t1
        /*-------------------------------2 метод--------------------------------*/
    --перебор каждой записи

    declare @c int      --количество, сколько раз отработает цикл
          , @i int      --поле I c таблицы
          , @j int = 1  --переменная для цикла

    select @c = count(*)
      from #t3

    --по циклу апдейтим таблицу #t1 и добавляем новую запись с не NULL значением в таблицу #t2
    while(@j <= @c)
    begin
        --номер нужной записи
        select @i = I
          from #t3
         where I2 = @j

        update #t1
           set B = t2.B
          from #t1 as t1
          join #t2 as t2 on t2.I = t1.I - 1
         where t1.I = @i

        --добавление новых записей не NULL
        insert into #t2
        select *
          from #t1
         where I = @i

           set @j = @j + 1
    end
    select * from #t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Как тут уже неоднократно сказано, понятие "предыдущей строки" в таблице не имеет смысла без явного указания способа упорядочивания этих строк. 
Поэтому будем предполагать, что порядок строк определяется неким столбцом 3:

```sql
-- заполним таблицу тестовыми данными
CREATE TABLE #t ([Столбец 1] INT, [Столбец 2] INT, [Столбец 3] INT identity(1, 1));
INSERT #t ([Столбец 1], [Столбец 2]) VALUES (1, 2), (6, NULL), (6, 7), (3, 9), (5, NULL), (9, NULL), (7, 5)

SELECT t1.[Столбец 1], t3.[Столбец 2]
FROM #t AS t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT MAX([Столбец 3]) AS [3]
    FROM #t
    WHERE [Столбец 3] <= t1.[Столбец 3]
        AND [Столбец 2] IS NOT NULL
    ) AS t2
JOIN #t AS t3 ON t2.[3] = t3.[Столбец 3]
ORDER BY t1.[Столбец 3]
```

Решение не претендует на оптимальность, просто первое, что пришло в голову.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте LAG и LEAD

```
SELECT  Столбец1, 
LAG(столбец1) OVER(ORDER BY столбец1) столбец2
или
LEAD(столбец1) OVER(ORDER BY столбец1) столбец2
FROM таблица;
```

Доступно с 2012 версии sql
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh231256.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396